# What is the recommended way to get the total number of entities of a kind stored in the datastore in dart?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-datastore

We are using the `gcloud` dart library to access the datastore. We would like to display the total number of users.

Of course, the simplest way to do this is:

```
db.query(User).run().length
```

but this would fetch all users.

Is there a way to run this query efficiently with the dart gcloud library? If not, will querying for all entities be a big performance issue and should we store the total number of users in a separate entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Datastore provides a number of **special entity kinds** which use the reserved `__xxx__` names and can be used to query datastore metadata.

Using this mechanism it is possible to e.g. query all namespaces by using `__namespace__`, query all kinds by using `__kind__`. [package:gcloud](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gcloud) contains already the special [Kind](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/gcloud/0.4.0/gcloud.db.meta_model/gcloud.db.meta_model-library.html) and [Namespace](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/gcloud/0.4.0/gcloud.db.meta_model/gcloud.db.meta_model-library.html) kinds for this purpose.

Any other metadata kind can be just defined by the user, among others, for querying kind counts.

Here is a snippet which allows one to count entities in Dart:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:appengine/appengine.dart';
import 'package:gcloud/db.dart';

Future main(List<String> args) async {
  await withAppEngineServices(() async {
    print(await getStats('Package'));
    print(await getStats('PackageVersion'));
  });
}

Future<Stats> getStats(String kind) async {
  final query = dbService.query(Stats)..filter('kind_name =', kind);
  final Stats stats = (await query.run().toList()).first;
  return stats;
}

@Kind(name: '__Stat_Kind__', idType: IdType.String)
class Stats extends ExpandoModel {
  @StringProperty(propertyName: 'kind_name')
  String kindName;

  @IntProperty()
  int count;

  String toString() => 'Stats(kind: "$kindName", count: $count)';
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning/clarifying that the Datastore Statistics are not real time, rather generated periodically (once a day?). If real time count is needed, you would have to use a separate counter that gets updated as users are added/deleted.

Comment: should the statistics be available with the datastore emulator?